# Is there a way to do a list comprehension where you append lists?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example i know in Python you can append a list to list.

```
list = [a,b,c]

list += [d,e,f]

print(list)
```

> [a,b,c,d,e,f]

Is there a way to accomplish this is list comprehension. I know we can define a list based on element, but is there a way to create a new list with list comprehension where i am define a segment of the list each iteration. Ie.

```
list = [function_that_returns_a_list(var) for var in vars]
```

Comment: List comprehension  should be used when useful not because we must always use it

Comment: are you trying to [flatten a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)?

Comment: in list comprehension you can add single element to list - ie. `d` - but not list - `[d,e,f]` . You would have to use second `for` to add every element from `[d,e,f]`  to main list.